# Getting "unable to get local issuer certificate" Errors When Installing Node Packages or Node_Modules Using Yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm working on a Gatsby js project and recently ran into issues installing packages using yarn. I am getting `unable to get local issuer certificate` errors.

I've scoured the web and found a few possible solutions from `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g` to adding brew packages `brew install automake autoconf libtool dpkg pkgconfig nasm libpng`, non of which worked.

Node v12.16.3, Yarn 1.22.10, Homebrew 2.5.11

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: That may be it. It's a company issued computer. But it doesn't explain why it was working before. Do you think they added additional security within the proxy?

Comment: It could be. I guess that using `npm` outputs the same result isn't?

Comment: You are correct